# Hiding elements in a diagram

Tags: jointjs

I have a read-only diagram to visualize some data.  My end users would like to "filter" the data such that only a subset of the data may be shown at one time.  I realize that I can redraw the whole diagram each time I apply a filter omitting the elements that are not to be shown but I am wondering if there is a way that I can simply "hide" some existing elements dynamically and then subsequently re-show them.

To try and make crystal clear, if this were a web page instead of a diagram, I would draw the analogy of applying the CSS of `display: none` to elements of my choosing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually do the same with a JointJS diagram elements/links. For example:

```
myElement.attr('./display', 'none')
```

hides the whole SVG group element in which the element is rendered. Note the `'.'` is a special selector that points to the whole group. If you want to hide only a certain SVG subelement, you can do it similarly, e.g. for the `joint.shapes.basic.Rect` element, you'd do:

```
myRect.attr('rect/display', 'none')
```

This hides only the rectangle (the SVG `<rect>` element referenced by the tag name `rect` in the `attrs` object - that we modify via the `attr()` method.

Comment: Thanks for explaining different between '.' and 'rect'.