# Hide Link in JointJs

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I have a JointJs model that includes many elements and links.  Most of the links I wish to display as lines between elements, but for certain types of links I want them to be invisible and undiscoverable to the user.  I've tried a few different things that have gotten me close, but I was wondering if someone had a better or more complete solutions.

Things I've tried:

```
link.attr({'.connection': {opacity: 0.0}});
```

This does indeed make the link invisible to the user, but still shows up and is editable when the user's mouse moves over it.

```
link.attr({'.connection': {display: non}});
```

This doesn't even place the link on the palette, which does succeed in hiding it from the user, but is problematic because it is no longer tracked by the model.

For a little more background information, these links can exist but cannot be created or utilized by the user, so I don't want them to be presented to the user.  However, when I query the palette for all of the links, I still want these to be present.

Thanks for any help or ideas you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have is hiding all the elements of the link (in the [doc](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Link:attr) they explain which are these elements).

I made this function to do it :

```
var attrObject = {
    '.connection': {display:"none"}, //the link
    '.marker-target': {display:"none"}, 
    'text': {display:"none"}, //because I have a label
    'rect': {display:"none"}, //second element of label
    '.connection-wrap': {display:"none"},//a bigger link highliting on hover
    'g.marker-vertices': {display:"none"}, //vertice of the link
    'g.link-tools': {display: 'none'}, // the button to delete the link
    'g.marker-arrowheads': {display:"none"} //the arrow to change link targets
};
link.attr(attrObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dargor.  I wasn't aware of those other elements associated with the link, and therefore they were still active on mouseover/mouse clicks.  I ended up doing as you said and setting opacity: 0, pointerEvents: none, and visibility: hidden to those objects.  It might be cleaner to add a baseCls parameter to the link with those three attributes as I believe that would then apply those to all child elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
this.attr("./display", "none");
```

(see also [Hiding elements in a diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114905/hiding-elements-in-a-diagram) )

Comment: This solution is the right way to hide a link in jointjs (or more generally speaking a jointjs element), as the accepted answer in the suggested link was made by the creator of jointJs.