# Show hidden elements in JointJS

Tags: javascript, jointjs

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27135067/2549258) shows how to hide visible elements. I want to create action for switching visibilities some elements. According to [documentation](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Element.prototype.removeAttr) I need to use `element.removeAttr` to remove some attributes. I can see removed `./display', 'none'` attribute, but on UI elements are still hidden - they should be visible.

Do you know what I'm missing? Should I rerender UI somehow?

Below is my event.

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', function switchTaskVisibility(...args) {
  const selectedItem = args[0];
  const successors = graph.getSuccessors(selectedItem.model);
  const tasks = successors.filter(function isElementOfTypeTask(element) {
    const type = element.prop('type');
    if (type === 'task') return element;
  });
  console.log(tasks);

  const hasVisibleTasks = selectedItem.model.prop('hasVisibleTasks');
  if (hasVisibleTasks) {
    tasks.forEach((element) => {
      element.attr('./display', 'none');
    });
  }
  else {
    tasks.forEach((element) => {
      element.removeAttr('./display');
    });
  }

  // HERE I CAN SEE THAT DISPLAY ATTRIBUTE SWITCHES CORRECTLY
  // BUT AFTER FIRST HIDING OF ELEMENTS I CANNOT MAKE THEM VISIBLE IN UI
  console.log(graph.getSuccessors(selectedItem.model)); 

  selectedItem.model.prop('hasVisibleTasks', !hasVisibleTasks);
});
```

Thanks,

Rafal

Answer (score 1):

I found some workaround. From some reason `removeAttr` doesn't rerender elements properly, so I tested `visibility` property like this:

```
  const hasVisibleTasks = selectedElement.prop('hasVisibleTasks');
  if (hasVisibleTasks) {
    cells.forEach((element) => {
      element.attr('./visibility', 'hidden');
    });
  }
  else {
    cells.forEach((element) => {
    element.attr('./visibility', 'visible');
  });
```

And works fine. But I still don't understand why `element.removeAttr('./display')` didn't rerender UI earlier.

Best regards,

Rafal

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the solution, Why you are using const data type for hasVisibleTasks as it seems the value of this variable is changing in run-time.

Comment: Hi Amy, note that in this case I'm not mutating the data of const hasVisibleTasks. This is only needed to check condition. Everytime when event is invoked new const hasVisibleTasks is created from selectedItem.model.prop('hasVisibleTasks') so it should work fine. And this value changes if I'm repeating click event on some element.